# Cookie not memorize the right value of variable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

In *code-behind* of my aspx page I create this cookie:

```
cookieidUserArea = new HttpCookie("idUserArea");
cookieidUserArea.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
cookieidUserArea.Values.Add("", idUserArea.ToString());
Response.Cookies.Add(cookieidUserArea);
```

To display the value of the variable stored in the cookie I used:

```
Response.Write(Request.Cookies["idUserArea"].Value + "<br />");
```

The value memorized in cookie it should be :

```
AA40
```

instead I have

```
=AA40
```

the presence of the symbol **=** in the cookie memorized produce problems in the application in the following steps.

I have tried this Replace without success:

```
cookieidUserArea.Values.Add("", idUserArea.ToString().Replace("=", ""));
```

Anybody know how can I resolve do this?

Can you suggest?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set "=" on `idUserArea`? What is the code that set values for `idUserArea`?

Comment: I am sure Sir ... the value on idUserArea is stored in database and I have AA40 ... If manually edit the cookie and delete the symbol = and restart the browser the application asp net regulary working

Comment: It seems `idUserArea` doesn't contain '=' symbol, so the `Replace` method can't remove it. Check a code before `Response.Write`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you use multi-value cookie. I suppose you want to use it like this instead:

```
cookieidUserArea.Value = idUserArea.ToString();
```

Alternatively you can retrieve the value like:

```
Request.Cookies["idUserArea"].Values[""]
```

Bottom line - don't mix single value and multi-value approach.

Answer (score 0):

As said before if you want to store just one value you can pass it n the constructor of the cookie, something like that:

```
cookieidUserArea = new HttpCookie("idUserArea",idUserArea.ToString());
cookieidUserArea.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookieidUserArea);
```